# How do I forward a domain to Django website?

Tags: django, cgi, wsgi, forward

Suppose, I have a django site e.g.  https://desk.one.net . I have another subdomain e.g.    https://desk.two.com  .   I want, https://desk.two.com will give the same content of https://desk.one.net . But it result in an unwanted situation. The browser give me this: https://desk.two.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi, and it display another page located in https://desk.one.net rather than the content of http://desk.one.net itself !!! Simply speaking, I want to have a subdomain to be forwarded to another site, but the site must be a "django based !" site. (Or maybe it has something to do with cgi or wsgi ?). Thank you.

Comment: You can configure nginx, apache, etc. to do forwarding

Comment: Thank's you for fast response. Let me try, hope that I will have access on them

Answer (score 2):

```
# settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['desk.one.net', 'desk.two.com']
```

Then in Nginx (or Apache etc.. but I will give an example for Nginx) you must do something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name desk.one.net desk.two.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Then, wherever you manage the DNS records of your domain, you must add A records pointing to the IP address of your server.